# git - Reset number of commits

Tags: git, commit, git-commit

I created a branch from a master branch which has 2000+ commits. More precisely, I first pulled the master branch to my machine, made some modifications, created a new local branch and push it remotely.

For some reason, the number of commits has been transferred to my new branch. I'd like to reset this number to zero or, even better, to the number of commits I've actually made on the new branch. Any ideas?

Comment: A branch *head* is a commit, but colloquially a branch is usually thought of as all the commits reachable from the branch head but not another branch head (more or less). I am also confused, though, about what the OP actually wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start a new orphan branch so you can get rid of the previous history.

https://gist.github.com/seanbuscay/5877413

Comment: Let me try this solution first, I will come back later.

Comment: Thanks, more precisely ```git checkout --orphan orphan_name```. For future visitors: I had to work a bit on this: first delete my old branch because I wanted to get the same name, then create a new orphan branch with that same name.